# How can I create Dictionary Type of Object from JSON type of string

Tags: string, json, dictionary, c#-2.0

I am looking to create a dictionary type of object from below string without using any extension class. I would prefer to write a .net class which will do serialize and deserialize it.

```
string userDetails = "{"FullName":"Manoj Singh","username":"Manoj","Miles":2220,"TierStatus":"Gold","TierMiles":23230,"MilesExpiry":12223,"ExpiryDate":"31 January 2011","PersonID":232323,"AccessToken":"sfs23232s232","ActiveCardNo":"232323223"}";
```

I have got above string in my results, now I want to convert it into dictionary type of Object using .NET 2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was waiting since many days to have any response on it, unfortunately there were no response, well guys I resolved my problem with the help of this question [Can you Instantiate an Object Instance from JSON in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199718/can-you-instantiate-an-object-instance-from-json-in-net)

Thanks to all you who have seen this question!

Answer (score 1):

try this!!

```
Class deserialize<Class>(string jsonStr, Class obj) { /* ... */}

 var jstring = "{fname='Test', lname='test, oth='test'}";
 var p     = deserialize(jstring, new {fname="",lname=""});
 var x     = person.fname; //strongly-typed
```