# Accessing ASP Session Variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, list, session, variables

I know I can reference a simple session variable (ie: string) in javascript like this:

```
var SesVar = '<%= Session("MySessionVariable") %>';
alert(SesVar);
```

But the problem I have is that I have an ASP.NET generic list object stored in Session.Contents. The object looks like this:

```
Public Class LetterReason

Private _reasonCode As String
Public Property ReasonCode() As String
    Get
        Return _reasonCode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _reasonCode = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _reason As String
Public Property Reason() As String
    Get
        Return _reason
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _reason = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I've stored a list of this object in session contents like so:

```
Dim lsReasons As New List(Of LetterReason)

lsReasons = MyWCF.Get(reasons)

Session.Contents("lsReasons") = lsReasons
```

Problem is, when I use the code above (SesVar), it returns this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LetterWriterASP2.ServiceReference1.LetterReason]
```

Is there any way I can access a list stored in session contents through javascript?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the evaluation binding tag will automatically call the ToString() method on the whatever it finds in the `Session` object.

So, if:

```
var SesVar = '<%= Session("MySessionVariable").ToString() %>';
```

has a meaningful implementation (e.g. it is a string, or a value type), then you'll get what you expect.

However, in your example, you're storing an instance of the class, `LetterReason`, for which the default `object` ToString() virtual method call will return the name of the class.

The answer depends what you want to do with the result.  You can't trivially use a .NET object in JavaScript, the data is going over a domain boundary (i.e. out of your .NET website and over the network and then into the DOM of a HTML page).

You will need to serialise it in some way, probably JSON. Use an approach like this: [Can you Instantiate an Object Instance from JSON in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199718/can-you-instantiate-an-object-instance-from-json-in-net)

That's if you need all the richness of the class.  If you're just looking for specific properties/methods, you could have:

```
var reasonCode = '<%= ((LetterReason)Session("MySessionVariable")).ReasonCode() %>';
var reason = '<%= ((LetterReason)Session("MySessionVariable")).Reason() %>';
```

So, here you'll need to cast your session instance to your particular class (plain .net `System.Object` are stored in the Sessions, giving you maximum flexibility) and then take the property you want.

However, serialising the object from .NET to JSON would be much the best solution, as it's flexible and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I handle client/server communications (such as accessing state on the server) asynchronously using a combination of WebServices and JQuery.  This pattern has a very small payload when compared to the built in asp.net AJAX toolkit and will handle your scenario very well.

This article is a great example to get started: http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your list that way, because the object you're storing in Session is specific to .NET, and JavaScript doesn't know what it is or how to parse it. You would need to convert the array to something more universally understood, like a delimited string or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON serializing the value - here's a helper method I wrote:

```
public static string JsonSerialize<T>(T tItem)
{
    if (null == Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(DataContractAttribute)))
    {
        bool canSerialize = false;
        if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
        {
            foreach (Type t in typeof(T).GetGenericArguments())
            {
                if (t.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    canSerialize = true;
                }
                else if (!(null == Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(DataContractAttribute))))
                {
                    canSerialize = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    canSerialize = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (canSerialize == false)
        {
            throw new SerializationException(String.Format("Cannot JsonSerialize instance of type {0} because {0} is not decorated as a DataContract.", typeof(T).FullName));
        }
    }

    string sResult = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            jsonSerializer.WriteObject(ms, tItem);
            sResult = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    return sResult;
}
```

Then, on the client side, use ASP.NET's client side library to deserialize:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(mySessionVarString, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to Serialize that list into XML or JSON or somthing parsable.  Dumping a complex session var onto a page like in your sample is basically doing a ToString() on the list instance, which will spit out nothing you can use.